# How can I affix carpet to a vertical surface?

Tags: drywall, walls, studs, carpet

My house was built back when it was fashionable to put the basement staircase in the middle  of the floor. What that means is that I have a couple of four-foot walls in the middle of my living room that block off the hole that's opened up for the stairs.

My cats love to hang out on top of these short walls. This makes me nervous because the walls are made of drywall and paint (over studs and frame), so there's nothing for the cats to grip on when they jump up or walk along the 5-inch wide top edge.

I think it would be interesting and fun (to them and me) for me to install carpet on the top and sides of these mini-walls to solve this problem.

**Question:**

- Should I put screws through the carpet, through the drywall, and into the studs?
- Should I use really long staples?
- Should I glue powerful magnets to the back side of the carpet in order to grab on to the screw/nail heads?
- How can I minimize the risks of

  1. the carpet coming loose when sheer pressure is applied and
  2. of the cats injuring themselves on a screw that pokes out of the carpet?

Comment: A note of caution: Anything you do will destroy the surface of the wall when the carpet is removed.

Comment: Minimize the risk of screw damage to cats by not using screws. Or, just make sure the screws are securely fastened. Really, the _head_ of the screw will be the part that _might_ come in contact with a cat, and screw heads generally aren't sharp. If you find a sharp screw head, toss it in the bin and get a new one. Screws are cheap. Also, I removed the "best" part of the question because that's opinion since you haven't defined criteria for "best".

Comment: @SteveWellens  Unless OP glues the carpet to the wall, I doubt the surface will be destroyed.  There will be small screw/staple holes in the wall, but usually they are easy to repair.

Comment: If I had done this for the last cat I had, I would have found her hanging by one hind leg with her claws stuck in the carpet.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't worry about the top. Cats have good balance, and a 4' fall isn't likely to hurt them.

If they would really rather climb than jump...

Carpeted "cat trees" often use staples, but those are usually driven directly into wood. Others just rely on glue.

You don't tell us how long these walls are or whether there are internal studs between the outer framing pieces, but I'd be tempted to go with something like screws driven through somewhat wider washers (so they can't pull through the carpet's weave) driven into the frame. Washer-head screws would of course be an alternative.

But this isn't exactly ticket science. Ten pounds or so of cat isn't a lot of load, and if it fails at this height see above comments re falling.

Comment: Yeah. OP wants entertainment. Nothing more entertaining than watching a cat twist when it falls so that it lands on its feet. Sadly, high-speed video equipment is usually required to actually be able to see it happen. A four-foot drop is nothing for a cat unless it's old, then it wouldn't jump up four feet anyway.

Comment: Also, I never noticed your avatar is a cat. How appropriate!

Comment: I believe it's a 4 ft. drop into the living room on one side and a 4 ft. + stairwell drop into the basement on the other side.

Comment: @mackm Ah. Missed that. Still not sure carpeting the top would help,  but it shouldn't hurt and might be appreciated.

Comment: @FreeMan: I identify as cat more than ape, though that varies from scrawny alleycat to something much larger depending on mood..

Comment: @MackM - Thank you for recognizing that the drop is different on different sides.

Comment: @FreeMan - There might be entertainment involved, but my question was definitely more about safety.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would build a wooden frame that I could simply hang over the wall—think inverted U shape—and staple/glue the carpet to the frame.  The frame would stay in place by means of gravity, whereas if you simply laid carpet over the wall, it's possible the cats' clawing at it could cause it to shift.  You could use 1x lumber, or plywood strips.

Answer (score 3):

I would use cabinet making staples - there are long narrow staples about 1.5" long, the loop will catch the weave of the carpet backing and the long points will reach the edge timbers of the wall even through drywall. you'll need a suitable nailgun to shoot them in.

it may be possible to rent a suitable tool from a tool hire place near you.